# Graphics plot device - gWidgets on OSX

Tags: r, gtk, gwidgets

I'm in the process of building a GUI in R with gWidgets (so far with just gWidgetstcltk) and I've been asked to put in a plotting device. I've looked at gGraphics and installed RGtk2 and gWidgetsRGtk2 and cairoDevice. The first time I loaded the RGtk2 and cairoDevice libraries it asked me to install GTK+, I clicked yes and went through the step by step installer of GTK+, but now every time I do:

```
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
library(cairoDevice)
```

It still keeps asking me to install GTK+ with this step by step installer. If I click no it fails to load the package.

How do I resolve this on OSX - (I'm also worried about the end user using this on something like Windows - hopefully they won't have any issue).

Best,
Ben W.

Comment: Similarly library(RGtk2) still produces this behaviour of asking me to install GTK+ when I already have done.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868860/r-3-0-and-gtk-rgtk2-error/17593245#17593245 The only solution I know of is to compile the libraries.