# Error message installing Rattle for R on macOS 10.14.1

Tags: r, macos, rattle, rgtk2

My R console is 3.5.1. I want to install the rattle package on my Mac Mojave 10.14.1. I realize that you have to install RGtk2 first but still got error messaging even when loaded "from source"

```
> install.packages("RGtk2")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘RGtk2’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘RGtk2’

trying URL 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/src/contrib/RGtk2_2.20.35.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2793137 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RGtk2’ ...
** package ‘RGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for INTROSPECTION... no
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RGtk2’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/67/r1c_pfwn5ws6y7rsl2bp_qqh0000gn/T/Rtmpi55PMx/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RGtk2") :
  installation of package ‘RGtk2’ had non-zero exit status
> install.packages("GTK")
Warning message:
package ‘GTK’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1) 
> install.packages("RGtk2", dependencies=TRUE)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘RGtk2’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a distillation of content I originally posted on my [Johns Hopkins Data Science Specialization Community Mentor](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/pml-installingRattleOnMacOSX.md) Github site in August 2017, in response to student questions about how to install Rattle on OS X in order to produce fancy `rpart` plots with `rattle::fancyRpartPlot()`.

The install requires the gtk toolkit, and on the Mac one way to accomplish this is, per [R 3.0 and GTK+ / RGTK2 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868860/r-3-0-and-gtk-rgtk2-error):

1. [Install macports](https://www.macports.org/install.php) — tool for installing mac packages
2. run SUDO to install gtk2 on mac
    `sudo port install gtk2  ## (X11 -- not aqua)`
3. export new path 
   `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`
4. From command line R, enter install rgtk2 with
    `install.packages("RGtk2",type="source")` to compile from source
5. Install the rattle package
   `install.packages("rattle",type="source")`

**NOTE:** For the `RGtk2` install to work correctly from RStudio, one must first confirm that the `PATH` change listed above is applied to the shell that is used to start RStudio.

The most complete set of instructions is located at [Sebastian Kopf's Gist page](https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/9405675) and verified by my own install on June 17, 2017. Once installed, loading the rattle library will generate the following output in the R console.

[image]

In order to use `fancyRpartPlot()`, one will also need to install the `rpart.plot` package.

```
  install.packages("rpart.plot")
```

### Example: Fancy Rpart Plot of Iris Data

Here we've replicated the code needed to generate a fancy tree diagram with `caret` and `rattle` that is discussed in the Johns Hopkins Data Science Specialization *Practical Machine Learning* lecture on *Predicting with Trees*.

```
  library(caret)
  library(rattle)
  inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = iris$Species,
                                 p = 0.7,
                                 list = FALSE)
  training <- iris[inTrain,]
  testing <- iris[-inTrain,]
  modFit <- train(Species ~ .,method = "rpart",data = training)
  fancyRpartPlot(modFit$finalModel)
```

[image]

Comment: I followed your instructions but when I attemped to install "RGtk2" from the R prompt I got this message Error: unexpected input in "install.packages(‚"

Comment: @BobHoyt - Hmm... looks like the quotation marks were converted by the text editor to “RGtk2”, try instead `install.packages("RGtk2",type="source")`. Notice that “ is not equal to ".

Comment: This did give me the option to once again install GTK 2.24.17 (X11), which I did. Then I got the following message > library(rattle)
> rattle()
Error in .C("R_gtkInit", length(args), x = args, success = logical(1),  : 
  "R_gtkInit" not available for .C() for package "RGtk2"

Comment: I updated the Ports, installed XQuartz and followed every method by Greski and others and finally, I was able to successfully load RGtk2 and Rattle. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, and please accept the answer if it was helpful.